# How can I add diacritics in a Libreoffice document?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice since a while, but I am confused about the process of adding special characters and diacritics in a document. I read some posts on the Internet, but as far as I understood, it appeared to be a solution only for Linux users. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: This may not be viable for you, but I just set the system keyboard to US-International, which permits me to enter accented character by pressing the accent key, followed by the base letter - for example, á is generated by pressing **'** immediately followed by **a**.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the same in US-International. It works with the accent, but i need some extra symbols, like dots below letters, breves over letters, and length symbols over vowels. I work with semitic texts and i need these symbols for transliteration

Comment: You may want to try some of the solutions [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/7663/lo-writer-insert-special-characters-by-shortcut-keys/) or [here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/3527/special-characters/?answer=3579#post-id-3579). Or, you can use Autocorrect, and have it automatically replace sequences like `{'a}` with `á`.